# Export RigidBody Simulation as FBX animation?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, .fbx

I've made a rigid-body animation (explosion) which I'd like to export as fbx.

https://i.postimg.cc/J7yQw2Ky/ezgif-1-20d0b92cad.gif

After hours of reading the same question over and over, apparently it's impossible unless I use alembic.abc format. However, I need it to be fbx format to be able to import it into a Game Engine which doesn't support abc files.

I've previously purchased a similar explosion animation from Sketchfab in fbx format. It works perfectly. It appears to have been made using rigid-body physics so I have hope that this can be done with blender.

How would I export my animated rigid-body simulation, as fbx?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully managed to export the rigid-body simulation from blender, as an fbx animation.

1- I baked the animation as key-frames in Blender.

2- I used the "better fbx plugin" and exported with the default options for fbx(2016).

-At this point, the fbx exported with the animation, but still didn't work when imported into the game engine (Coppercube)-

3- I imported to UltimateUnwrap3D and exported the file as blitz3D animation file.

Resulting file size is only 196kb (mesh and animation) and works perfectly when imported into the game engine.

Comment: So you exported as a blitz3D file, not FBX?

Comment: Successfully exported as fbx (from blender), but then re-exported it as blitz (from Ultimate Unwrap), just to get the file-size down even further and fix the compatibility issue with Coppercube game-engine. I could have exported it as fbx from unwrap too, the file-size would have only been 2.5mb - but the tiny blitz file tempted me.